# How to filter history entries in GitHub for Windows?

Tags: tortoisesvn, github-for-windows

There seems to be no way to find a specific entry in the commit history, there is no search box (like the one in TortoiseSVN's "Show log" dialog), I also try right clicking the history list, but no menu is popup.

So how can I find a commit history quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be supported yet (when looking at the ["GitHub for Windows" release notes](http://windows.github.com/release-notes.html)).

Using an alternative client like [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) for that would be a good workaround, using the [Log Dialog](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/Screenshots#Log_Dialog).

[image: Log Dialog in TortoiseGit]